# Associated Labels in a dendrogram plot - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, label, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

I have the following set of data stored in file `stations.dat` :

```
       Station A 305.2 321.1 420.9 383.5 311.7 197.1 160.2 113.9 60.5 60.5 64.8 154.3
       Station B 281.1 304.0 353.1 231.9 84.6 20.9 11.7 11.9 31.1 75.8 133.0 235.3
       Station C 312.3 342.2 366.2 335.2 200.1  74.4 45.9   27.5 24.0   53.6 87.7 177.0
       Station D 402.2 524.5 554.9 529.5 347.5  176.8 120.2 35.0 12.6 13.3 14.0 61.6
       Station E 261.3 262.7 282.3 232.6 103.8  33.2 16.7   33.2 111.0  149.0 184.8 227.0
```

By using the following commands,

```
Z = linkage (stations.data,'ward','euc'); 
figure (1), dendrogram(Z,0,'orientation', 'right')
```

I get the figure below:
[image]

So cluster 1 components are 4,3,1 (Stations D,C and A, respectively) and cluster 2 are 5,2(Stations E and B).

I want to put the name of Stations on plot, but if I use the command:

```
set (gca,'YTickLabel', stations.textdata);
```

The figure I get is the following:
[image]

How can I associate data to respective names and plot in dendrogram.
I have 144 stations data. I used only 5 for illustration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ind = str2num(get(gca,'YTickLabel'));
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',stations.textdata(ind))
```

---

An easier way would be to specify the labels of the data points in the `dendrogram` call directly:

```
dendrogram(Z,0, 'Orientation','right', 'Labels',stations.textdata)
```

[image: dendrogram]