# How to put Label in a dendogram in Matlab using function dendrogram(tree, name, value)?

Tags: matlab, csv, customization, label, dendrogram

I have tried the following link (unfortunately, didn't work):
[Associated Labels in a dendrogram plot - MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779256/associated-labels-in-a-dendrogram-plot-matlab)
Instead of Station Ids, mine will be PDBId.

**My Problem:**
I am creating a dendrogram from a csv file **"similarity_nogrp.csv"** :

```html
PDBId 0         1         2           3             4     
1A06 1         0.05344457 0.439285476 0.46664877 0.40868216 
1B6C 0.05344457 1         0.03371103 0.029899324 0.033972369
1BO1 0.439285476 0.03371103 1         0.5579095 0.488785068 
1CDK 0.46664877 0.029899324 0.5579095 1         0.50682912 
1CJA 0.40868216 0.033972369 0.488785068 0.50682912 1 
1CSN 0.490366809 0.047467331 0.50842029 0.533638473 0.465180315
1E8X 0.036246998 0.002009194 0.057903016 0.066882369 0.058359239
```

Here, in first line,

PDBId is row Id,

0 1 2 3 4 are column numbers,

I want to label the leaf nodes as per PDBId, but as I am reading the csv file from 2nd column (only  numbers, leaving the PDBIds), later while setting 'Labels' as 'PDBId' in dendrogram(), I am getting error:

Here is my code:

```html
filename = 'D:\\matlab codes\\similarity_nogrp.csv'
X = csvread(filename,1,1) 
Z = linkage(X,'average')
C = cluster(Z, 'maxclust', 3)
H = dendrogram(Z,'Orientation','left','Labels',filename.PDBId)
```

The error for last line is:

```html
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

Please provide me a way such that I can use the PDBId as my labels for the leaf nodes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem is that you are trying to access a struct field of `filename`, but `filename` is a character array, not a struct. Also, `readcsv` can only read numeric values, so it won't get the labels for you anyway.

You can use [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) instead to get the row and column names, and then read the row names off of the table. Here's the code I used:

```
filename = 'D:\\matlab codes\\similarity_nogrp.csv';
T = tableread(filename,'ReadVariableNames', true, 'ReadRowNames', true)
X = T{:,:}; % Get the data from the table without row/col names
Z = linkage(X,'average')
C = cluster(Z, 'maxclust', 3)
H = dendrogram(Z,'Orientation','left','Labels',T.Properties.RowNames)
```

And the results I got:
[image: Results]

Comment: Thank you @Matthew