# How can I add labels to a polar dendrogram in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

1.) This is the code for polar dendrogram:

```
X= rand(100,2);
Y= pdist(X,'cityblock');
Z= linkage(Y,'average');
dendrogram(Z,'colorthreshold','default');
```

But I want to do the labelling of my text.data file as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779256/associated-labels-in-a-dendrogram-plot-matlab). I don't want numbering labels and want the text from my string file

---

Can we do the same labelling in case of polardendrogram

```
polardendrogram(Z,0,'colorthreshold','default');
zoom(0.8);
view(2);
```

if we have large data sets for rows labels ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably using the `polardendrogram` command from [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21983), correct?

If so, sweet! I wrote that about twelve years ago - nice to see that someone's using it!

So if you want to see the labels, you should probably do this.

1. Open the file `polardendrogram.m`
2. Go to the section `%Relabel leaves`, it starts at line 45.
3. Modify it so that it says the following:

---

```
%Relabel leaves
labels = get(gca, 'XTickLabel');
for i=minx+1:maxx-1
    [x,y]=pol2cart((((i-minx)/xrange)*(pi*11/6))+(pi*1/12),1.1);
    text(x,y,labels{i});
%     text(x,y,num2str(perm(i)));
end
```

This code will add the specified labels in, rather than always putting the row numbers.

---

4. Now you can call it as follows:

---

```
for i = 1:100
    labels{i} = ['label', num2str(i)];
end
X= rand(100,2);
Y= pdist(X,'cityblock');
Z= linkage(Y,'average');
numNodesToDisplay = size(X,1);
polardendrogram(Z, numNodesToDisplay, 'colorthreshold','default', 'Labels', labels);
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: Sir, I'm not getting it. I tried it but it is giving numbers for labels. Please give me one example if possible for data and label file if possible. I will be highly obliged to you.

Comment: @sumitmishra See my edit (`numNodesToDisplay`). I'm guessing you have a large number of nodes to display. If that's the case, then by default MATLAB will collapse some of the nodes (by default it displays only 30). The collapsed nodes will always display numbers, it doesn't matter if you supplied labels. So you can specify the full number of nodes, and I think this should give you what you need.